# factorial function - parallel processing

Tags: java, parallel-processing

i need to write **factorial function**(n!) in **parallel** computing on EREW PRAM system.
assume that we have n proccessors.
the complexity should be log n.
how can i do this?

Comment: Let's start with the basics: The you at least try it? If so, what did you get? Do you have any ideas of how this could work? Any ideas why your solution didn't work? Do you have any code to share? Is this home work?

Answer (score 2):

> we have n proccessors. the complexity should be log n.

The question makes no sense, since you're looking for an algorithm whose complexity (`log n`) *increases* as you add processors (i.e. increase `n`).

I am guessing that what you're meant to do is split the product `1*2*3*...*k` into `n` blocks of equal size, compute each sub-product on a separate processor, and then multiply the `n` results together.

Comment: I think the OP was just unfortunate when expressing himself. What he/she probably meant is:  we have p processors and the complexity should be log n

Comment: @DallaRosa: We can only guess what the OP meant. In your proposed correction the complexity (`log n`) is independent of the number of processors (`p`). To me, that doesn't make a whole lot of sense either.

Comment: if n=8 then:1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8 = p[1] compute 1*2, p[2] compute 3*4... now we have four resullts. continue on this way and finally we get log n. what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

In general you can divide the work N times for N processors and compute each independently. You can combine the results by multiplying the answers for each piece of work. e.g. the first task performed m!, the next (2m)!/m!, the third (3m!)/(2m!) etc. When you multiple the results you get n!.

BTW: You wouldn't do this for small values of `n` e.g less than 1000 because the overhead of starting new threads/task can be greater than the time it takes to do this in a single thread.

---

I suspect pseudo code won't be enough so here is an example

```
public enum CalcFactorial {;

    public static BigInteger factorial(long n) {
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (long i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        return result;
    }

    public static BigInteger pfactorial(long n) {
        int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        if (n < processors * 2)
            return factorial(n);
        long batchSize = (n + processors - 1) / processors;
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(processors);
        try {
            List<Future<BigInteger>> results = new ArrayList<Future<BigInteger>>();
            for (long i = 1; i <= n; i += batchSize) {
                final long start = i;
                final long end = Math.min(n + 1, i + batchSize);
                results.add(service.submit(new Callable<BigInteger>() {
                    @Override
                    public BigInteger call() throws Exception {
                        BigInteger n = BigInteger.valueOf(start);
                        for (long j = start + 1; j < end; j++)
                            n = n.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(j));
                        return n;
                    }
                }));
            }
            BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
            for (Future<BigInteger> future : results) {
                result = result.multiply(future.get());
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        } finally {
            service.shutdown();
        }
    }
}

public class CalcFactorialTest {
    @Test
    public void testFactorial() {
        final int tests = 200;
        for (int i = 1; i <= tests; i++) {
            BigInteger f1 = factorial(i * i);
            BigInteger f2 = pfactorial(i * i);
            assertEquals(f1, f2);
        }
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 1; i <= tests; i++) {
            BigInteger f1 = factorial(i * i);
        }
        long mid = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 1; i <= tests; i++) {
            BigInteger f2 = pfactorial(i * i);
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.printf("Single threaded took %.3f sec, multi-thread took %.3f%n",
                (mid - start) / 1e9, (end - mid) / 1e9);
    }
}
```

on an 3.72 GHz i7 prints

```
Single threaded took 58.702 sec, multi-thread took 11.391
```