# Why does this factorial method fail after 1676?

Tags: java, performance, int, biginteger

I have made a factorial method using BigInteger (because of the restraints of long), which is "infinite", but for some reason the returned value will not print when n > 1676 (returned value is n!). Here is my code:

```
private static BigInteger factorial (int n) {

    //init ans at 1
    BigInteger ans = BigInteger.ONE;

    //multiply ans by decreasing n
    while (n > 1) {
        ans = ans.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(n--));
    }

    //return ans after loop
    return ans;

}
```

I used an iterative method instead of a recursive method because I didn't want to cause a `Stackoverflow Exception`.
Here's what I know: `factorial(1676).toString().length() is 4679`, well under the int or even short overflow limit.
However, `System.out.println(factorial(1676))` works, while `System.out.println(factorial(1677)` prints nothing at all.
So that's all I know, and please help me if you can.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. My advice would be to use a debugger or add some print statements to see where exactly it's getting stuck.

Comment: "I used an iterative method instead of a recursive method because I didn't want to cause a stack overflow" – for 1700 stack frames? It would be sad if your Java VM implementation couldn't handle 1700 stack frames of such a trivial function.

Comment: @NPE Indeed. OP's code is working for me for at least 300,000.

Comment: Maybe OP is running this on something small.

Comment: It works fine. I had runned it under InteliJ on 2GHz Pentium - but you don't want to see the results:D Veeeery long numbers:)

Comment: Your issue may be as simple as a line too long for you IDE to print. Try just printing `"Done"` instead of the number, or `f.toString().substring(0,1000))` or, to get the full number, a loop with `System.out.println(str.substring(i,i+1000))`.

Answer (score 0):

Whell, your algoritm is correct, and under my machine it works fine. If you are interested in some boost, you could use pararell processing for it. Bacause you could split it into subfactorials,
like:

```
n=1*2*3*4....*(n-1)*n
```

You could split this list into more sublists:

```
n! = k*l*h
```

where

```
k=1*2*....*k
l=(k+1)*(k+2)*...*h
h=(h+1)*...*n
```

The gist is to compute submodules and then agregate them.

Here this topic was answered a while ago:
[factorial function - parallel processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469552/factorial-function-parallel-processing)

Comment: This is a one-liner in Java 8: `return IntStream.range(2,n+1).parallel().mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf).reduce(BigInteger::multiply).orElse(BigInteger.ONE);`. However, *computing* the number is not OP's issue.

Comment: I just wish I could use JDK8 at work:) Guava isn't the same:)

Comment: Guava *does* have support for this operation, fairly heavily optimized, in BigIntegerMath.factorial.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I think Bari meant that pre-8 Java with Guava doesn't match Java 8 without Guava with respect to syntax :) Of course, Guava *with* Java 8 is something completely different.